# Error while generating crystal report in c# windows application using crystal report

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, setup-deployment

Error occur while generate a crystal report after deployment .
I use visual studio 2010

```
Unhandled exception has occurred in your application.  If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue.  If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.Length cannot be less than zero.Parameter name:  length.
```

my code in the crystal report form

```
    private void crystalReportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        rd = new ReportDocument();
        String reportpath = Application.StartupPath;
        reportpath = reportpath.Substring(0, reportpath.LastIndexOf("bin"));
        rd.Load(reportpath + "PatientReportNonReactive.rpt");
        DataSet ds = prc.nonReactiveReportNew(cond);
        rd.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
        crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

Comment: There should be a stack trace.

Comment: there should be exception type and potentially message, too

Comment: The exception message is `Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: length.`  Obviously you are passing an invalid value to your report.